# AJAX path is not right

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a web application with a few cascading dropdown lists.  So I use ajax to update the value of the next dropdown list.  I put the javascript script in a separate file.

```
// Code that triggers when there is a change in Activity drop down.
    $('#ActivityId').change(function () {
        var activityId = $(this).val();

        // Empty the Workstation.
        $('#WorkstationId').empty();

        $('.showhide-workstation').show();

        var url = "~/WorkOrderSubmissions/GetWorkstationsByActivityJson";
        // AJAX call that re-populate Workstation drop down depending on the Activity selected.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { activityId: activityId },
            success: function (codes) {
                $('#WorkstationId').append('<option value=""></option>');
                $.each(codes, function (i) {
                    $('#WorkstationId').append('<option value = "' + codes[i].Value + '">' + codes[i].Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                $('#WorkstationId').append('<option value=""></option>');
            }
        }); // END $.ajax() on GetRejectCodesByActivityJson
    }); // END $('#ActivityId').change()
```

The code works when I run it from inside Visual Studio.  It does not work when I deploy it to my local web server.  I deploy it to

```
http://localhost/mea
```

When I open Developer Tools in Chrome, I see the error.

```
POST http://localhost/~/WorkOrderSubmissions/GetLinesByWorkorderJson 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried to to change the url to

```
url = ~/WorkOrderSubmissions/GetLinesByWorkorderJson
url = /WorkOrderSubmissions/GetLinesByWorkorderJson
url = WorkOrderSubmissions/GetLinesByWorkorderJson
```

None of them work. I thought ~ is supposed to go to the root of the web application, which is http://localhost/mea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~` syntax is only recognised by ASP.Net; it will be taken literally by any JS code. You need to provide the URL via your C# code to JS:

```
var url = '@Url.Content("~/WorkOrderSubmissions/GetWorkstationsByActivityJson")';
```

Or better yet:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetWorkstationsByActivityJson", "WorkOrderSubmissions")';
```

Comment: Side notes: obviously you need to properly encode Url when rendering in JavaScript (separate frequently asked question) as well as having JS separate from HTML is good practice - for that you'd need to pass such url via some other means like `data-` attribute of some HTML element.

Comment: The reason I separate the JS script is I have multiple cascading dropdowns. It will make the _Layout.cshtml long and ugly if I put it there.  Is there a way to pass the @Url.Content to the script.js file?

Comment: Yes there is - that would be the pattern of providing the URL of the request as a `data` attribute on the relevant element that @AlexeiLevenkov mentioned.